# Screwed up my 1TB HD iMac27 - I am running OSX 10.11.5 need to rebuild it in Terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, hard-drive, time-machine

**

### Not sure what I did but I need to regain the space on my 1TB HD. I have made a full back up and need to know the step by step commands in TERMINAL to do this. As you can see I have access to only 120GB.[image] I have attached info/ disc Util info

**

[image]

Comment: Please remove the pic and add the content as text! The pic **doesn't contain any** additional information besides the text. The downside of posting pics of Terminal outputs is that you can't easily copy and paste parts of it!

Comment: Curiously, did you recently convert an HFS volume to CoreStorage volume? If so, could you please type 'history | grep -i diskutil' and attach the output?

Answer (score 1):

Since you have made a full backup, I recommend a full wipe and restore.

120GB plus CoreStorage plus "I had 1TB before" sounds like this is a fusion drive that you have disconnected.

Reboot the machine in recovery mode (Command-R at power-on) and open Disk Utility. Very easy from there to reformat the internal drives either separately or as a fusion drive again. Then either restore the Time Machine backup or install a new OS and then import your data.

Dealing with core storage volumes in the terminal is *very* fiddley. Step C depends on the output of step B etc. Quick and easy in Disk Utility.